# Frattini subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is true that if G is finite and it is not equal to the identity then we will always have a Frattini subgroup of G that isn't equal to G, it seems to me intuitively that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Frattini subgroup of a *finite* non trivial group is a proper subgroup. This is based on two known facts:

1. every finite (and not empty) partially ordered set has maximal elements, so in particular every finite group has a maximal subgroup,
2. the Frattini subgroup is the intersection of all maximal subgroups.

In the infinite case it can happen that the Frattini subgroup is not proper, exactly if the group has no maximal subgroup.